# SWIFT: CAGradientLayer not shown property in TableViewCell programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview, cagradientlayer

My CAGradientLayer in a tableViewCell looks like this. I am not using xib or storyboard, how can I apply the layer. to cover the frame?

[image]

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    //awakefromnib wont work if programmatically
    selectionStyle = .none
    backgroundColor = .black
    self.setupView()
 }

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    self.setupGradientlayer()    
}

fileprivate func setupGradientlayer() {
    gradientlayer.frame = self.bounds

    gradientlayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.secBlack().withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor]
    gradientlayer.locations = [0.4, 1]
    
    layer.insertSublayer(gradientlayer, above: self.userImg.layer)
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    //empty since I'm not using xib or storyboard.  only code programmatically
}
```

Comment: update your frame with draw rect ```override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        gradientlayer.frame = self.boundss
    }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` this method for updating your layer frame. This method called every time whenever cell frame is changed.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        gradientlayer.frame = self.boundss
}
```